# Cypress - I need to verify that the result of the function is the same as the value of the slug element

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

```
it.only('Create new film', () => {

    function randomStringFc() {
      var a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var n = "1234567890";
      var t = function(input, length) { return Array(length).fill(input).map(function(v) { return v[Math.floor(Math.random() * v.length)] }).join(''); }
      var m = "testFilm-" + t(a+n, 8);
      return m;
    }

    cy.contains('Create new', { timeout: 12000 }).click()
    cy.get('#title', { timeout: 12000 }).then( input => {

        let filmName = cy.wrap(input).type(randomStringFc())
        
        cy.get('#slug').should('have.value', filmName)
    
    })

})
```

Timed out retrying after 10000ms: expected '<input#slug.form-control>' to have value { Object (userInvocationStack, specWindow, ...) }, but the value was 'testfilm-fruh5tn5'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you work with chains. There's no meaningful return value.

You need to use another variable to do what you want:

```js
cy
  .get('#title', { timeout: 12000 })
  .then(input => {
    const randomString = randomStringFc();
    cy
      .wrap(input)
      .type(randomString);
    cy
      .get('#slug')
      .should('have.value', randomString);
  });
```